# Replacing the popup tub drain plug

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, plumbing-fixture

The drain plug I had broke and I decided to change it. The problem is that no matter how hard I tried, I just couldn't remove the broken one. You can even see that I managed to break one part of it using too much force. I tried applying WD-40 and used cobra pliers.

**NOTE:** The inside part of plug is missing (that part was broken so I took it off and threw it).

[image]

Since the piston is stuck, and no way to remove it, I am thinking about buying the new drain as well (If that's the correct name of it - maybe it's called basin waste).

Here are more photos of it:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how that specific model of a drain is called? Also should I apply plumbers putty to it? I found this white thing on photos, so I am not sure if it had plumbers putty applied.

Comment: Are you sure your drain is meant to be taken apart?  How about just getting a new one?

Comment: Yeah, for the price you're better off replacing the assembly. You'll have fresh chrome then. I did mine recently. Big Orange had them in chrome and stainless.

Comment: Thanks, I've ordered the new assembly. I guess I won't be needing the plumbers putty as it comes with silicone gaskets.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, it's called a tub shoe or drain assembly. I also believe plumber's putty is no longer recommended for this type of application. A new drain assembly kit should come with everything you need. Just read the box's instructions before leaving the hardware store, or the sales associate should be able to tell you everything you need.